# REDCap Section Header Color Change

Tags: formatting, redcap

I would like to change the default color of section headers in REDCap. Under the field type, "Begin New Section (with optional text)", the default color of header is yellow - [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg5WA.png). Is there some code that can be used to change the color?

I have tried to insert a 1*1 and fill the cell property with a different color, hoping it would change the color of the entire header. However, it is not what I am looking for [(see here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ6Kh.png).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the "Begin New Section" section, you may want to utilize the Descriptive Text field. I feel that it's more customizable, and you can even put in branching logic so that headings only appear when relevant questions and choices are answered and selected, respectively. Within the descriptive text, you can use the following HTML code (and customize it to your liking):

**Text**

I would highly look up the following HTML lines:
div class=
div style=
span style=
font-size:

and play around as appropriate till you get the output that you like.